# label in MDI parent form do not remain in background of child form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Please guide and help me.

I have a MDI parent form which has a label at its center (to display application name in center). On opening a form in this MDI parent, this label should appear on back side of newly opened form, but on showing a child form, label appears in front of newly opened form (appears like newly opened form is between label and MDI parent).

How to manage it please guide me.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public partial class MyMdiForm : Form
{
    public MyMdiForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        foreach (Control control in Controls)
        {
            if (control is MdiClient)
                control.Paint += mdiBackgroundPaint;
        }
    }

    private void mdiBackgroundPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        var mdi = sender as MdiClient;
        if (mdi == null) return;

        e.Graphics.Clip = new System.Drawing.Region(mdi.ClientRectangle);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("*** YOUR NAME HERE ***",this.Font,Brushes.Red,100F,100F);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jvanrhyn, it solved the porblem. Just one question pelase. My issue was normal ? I mean to say is this correct working of MDI form that if they have controls in them, controls come over child forms ? or it was some thing wrong in my code ? thanks alot for yoru shring and precious time.

Comment: Yes, this is normal. The MDI container is a host for forms and not really for controls, with the exception of docking toolbars and statusbar etc to the top, bottom and sides of your MDI form.

Comment: It's perfect for me to display in background the list of conditional compilation symbols. :)

Answer (score 4):

This will hide the label while you have active MDI Children en show it again once there is no active child anymore.

```
    private void Form1_MdiChildActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ActiveMdiChild != null)
            label1.SendToBack();
        else
            label1.BringToFront();
    }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks jvanrhyn for replying. on what event of what form I shoud code this ? Please guide one more thing. Is this correct behaviour or it is somethign wrong with me. thanks

Comment: This is the MdiChildActivate event of the MDI form. This event is fired both when a child is activated and deactivated.

Comment: jvanrhyn I tried this code. It solved problem partially. On loading child form label in back form (mdi parent) got invisible and when I close child form lable come back. But it again give strange looks like going and coming of label. Can't there some why that lable may stay there always remain visible on back of child form and if no child form will be open lable will be first layer. At the time when a child form comes label become disappear when I close child form it comes again. Please advice. Thanks

Comment: I have posted another solution that will paint the text onto the MDI surface. You will therefore not use a label.

Comment: works fine on windows but when used it in Linux through mono control on mdi disappears on clicking on child form , please help me out

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your label is not added to the `MdiClient` (i.e. the grey Mdi container) but to the form.

But unfortunately, AFAIK, it's not possible to add controls to an MdiClient.

The only way is drawing what you want on the `Paint` event of the MdiClient, as suggested in this article:

http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/NET/Code/Libraries/Windows/MDI_Client_Area_Painting/article.asp

Comment: Thanks for replying dibEmALL, Actually I am new to winforms. The label I am reffering I added on Mdi parent (I added a simple form and make it MDIParent of other form, I did not added a seprate MDI parent type of form). If I do not open new form label appears on MDI parent.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I did one trick and it works for me. We usually write an application name in the center and expect it to show to the user. And many people here said that MdiParent is only for Forms and not for other tools like we cannot hide label/panel behind MdiChild form.

So what I did is I wrote all the things like application name, contact, email etc etc etc in a `new Form` say `frmMdiBody`, Set its `formBorderStyle = None` and set the desired length of the form, `StartPosition = CenterScreen` and in `Timer.Tick`, I wrote the following : (Didn't work for me in Load event)

```
  Dim NewMDIChild As frmMdiBody = MdiChildren.OfType(Of frmMdiBody)().SingleOrDefault
  If NewMDIChild Is Nothing Then
      NewMDIChild = New frmMdiBody
      NewMDIChild.MdiParent = Me
      NewMDIChild.Show()
  End If
```

This above code also checks if there is one form open so that it won't open many `frmMdiBody` again and again as we are writing in Timer.Tick event

Someone can rectify me if I am wrong. I'd do the changes too if seems appealing.